# Sort a list of object w.r.t to a particular member/state in descending order

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have a list of java object that have 4 members.

```
int id;
String name;
String age;
int order;
```

I am using his code to sort object fields in ascending order according to **if** condition.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<com.MyObject>() {

          public int compare(com.MyObject object1, com.MyObject object2) {

            if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
            return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());

          }else if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("age")){
            return object1.getAge().compareTo(object2.getAge());

          }else{
            return object1.getOrder() - object2.getOrder();
          }
      }
  });
```

I want to add another condition `if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("nameReverse"))` If this will be the case the list should be sorted in descending order.

Comment: I use Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder()); but it throws exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Collections class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28java.util.Comparator%29) has a `reverseOrder` method which returns a reverse `Comparator` for a given comparator. IMO, it would be more cleaner to not modify the `Comparator` if all you want to do is get a reverse `Comparator`.

A bit of sample code:

```
public class Person {

    public static void testComparator() {
        Person p1 = new Person("c");
        Person p2 = new Person("a");
        Person p3 = new Person("b");
        List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3);
        Collections.sort(persons, PersonComparator.INSTANCE);
        System.out.println("After normal sorting: " + persons);
        Collections.sort(persons, Collections.reverseOrder(PersonComparator.INSTANCE));
        System.out.println("After reverse sorting: " + persons);
    }

    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Person [name=").append(name).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}

class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    public static final PersonComparator INSTANCE = new PersonComparator();

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }

}
```

Comment: I use Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder()); but it throws exception.

Comment: You need to pass in your original `Comparator` to the `reverseOrder()` for this to work.

Comment: I added this line to code but it throws compile time error else `code`if(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("nameReverse")){
                return Collections.sort(list,Collections.reverseOrder());`code`

Comment: As Sanjay said, `Collections.reverseOrder` requires an argument, which is probably what that exception that you haven't shown us says.

Comment: Update your original post with the new code snippet. The simplest way is to store the original Comparator in a variable and pass it to the `Collections.reverse` method.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with reverse sorting code for name field? Ascending order code for name field is in my question. Please update it in your answer.

Comment: Updated; run the `main` method of the `Person` class.